# Package 'perl-Env' not found

Tags: suse, sles, zypper

Hi I'm trying to install `perl-Env` package using `zypper`. But the installation fails with the following error:

```
user@sles:~> sudo zypper -n install perl-Env
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Package 'perl-Env' not found.
```

How can I install this package in my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSUSE doesn't strip modules from the core library. [Env](http://p3rl.org/Env) is part of the `perl` package, no need to install anything else.

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/Env.pm 
perl-5.26.1-15.87.x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba. I installed the perl package directly using `zypper install perl`